# gradle / intellij - shared test resource(s)

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a **gradle** based project with 8 subprojects. Each of these has test code that relies on a folder with a number of .csv files for content. I'd rather not copy this folder into the test path of each subproject.

Is there a way to tell gradle to look for the files in a common location?

How about for IntelliJ? I tried indicating the files were a 'test resource' but haven't figured out how to get each sub-module to find them (without resorting to '../..' style notation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did that providing the path to the common files folder on sourceSets in the build.gradle file:

```
sourceSets {
    test { 
        resources {
        srcDirs = ["src/test/resources", "src/main/resources/db"]
    }
}
```

Not sure if that's a clean way to do that, but for me it's better than copypasting the same files over multiple locations.

Comment: Would this go into the main build.gradle or into the subprojects?

Comment: I was able to get this to work using `srcDirs = ["${rootDir}/resources"]`. IntelliJ isn't happy though. Still working on that.